# Is there a way to calc(div's height - some unit)?

Tags: css

Say there's a `div.outer`. Inside this div, there are some images and paragraphs. `div.outer`'s height is dynamic because its height is the sum of its children height. However, is there a way to subtract some unit from div.outer's height? Like calc(div's height - 50px)? I happen to need this for some cases.

Comment: No, as its height is dynamic. You'll have to use JS for this one.

Comment: You want to apply it on the `div.outer` itself or on one of its children? For the former, how would this not end up in an infinite loop? For the latter, yes you can use percentages, assuming .outer is relatively positioned.

Comment: You can probably do that using flex, depending on what you're actually trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't use of pure css,because for use of calc,we need to height of outside `div`,and we can't access to it with css.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var outerHeight = $('.outer').height();
  $('.outer').height(outerHeight - 40);
})
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var outerHeight = $('.outer').height();
  $('.outer').height(outerHeight - 40);
})
```

```css
.outer {
   background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inside">
     <p>This is test</p>
     <p>This is test</p>
     <p>This is test</p>
     <p>This is test</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No. You do NOT have to use jQuery. Plain javascript does it just as well or better.

Comment: @Rob, hello my friends, what is wrong in my answer? if you think javascript is better , so show it please.

Comment: The question is tagged CSS... One could at least pretend to try to give some hints about CSS.

Comment: I don't get the question, so I can't give any solution no. But you answered it, so I guess you've got it clearer than me, and are able to say at least why it's not possible through CSS if you think it is not.

Comment: @Kaiido, for use of `calc`,we need to `height` outside div,and we can't access to it with css.

Comment: Well include whatever you've got to say about it in your answer directly, not in comments to some guy like me.

Comment: @Kaiido, you are right,thank you.i updated my answer.

Comment: My point is you claimed one needs to download jQuery and use that as the only way to solve this issue and I am saying one does NOT need to use jQuery at all to solve this and, if anything, it is simpler, easier and faster to use plain javascript.